# Trouble configuring external monitor with xrandr

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I have a Lenovo laptop with a NVidia graphic card and an external monitor, and I'm struggling to configure it so that the monitor extends the laptop screen on the left.

Output of `xrandr -q`: https://pastebin.com/wXsLCKeD The external monitor corresponds to the output DP-0, and the laptop screen to LVDS-1-1.

I've tried the following:

```
xrandr \
  --output DP-0 --mode 1920x1080 --left-of LVDS-1-1 \
  --output LVDS-1-1 --mode 1920x1080

xrandr \
  --output DP-0 --auto --left-of LVDS-1-1 \
  --output LVDS-1-1 --mode auto      

xrandr \
  --output LVDS-1-1 --auto --right-of DP-0 \
  --output DP-0 --auto
```

But all these screw up the resolution completely ([photo of the main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9IQe.jpg), [photo of the laptop screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLAVS.jpg)).

The only thing I've managed to get working is to have the same output on both screens:

```
xrandr --output DP-0 --same-as LVDS-1-1
```

My graphic drivers are up to date. [Here's the output](https://pastebin.com/fLqJKDxD) of `lspci` if that's of any help.